# Iterate through JSON in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures

I'm looking for something like `forEach` for a JSON array in MySQL.

I manager IDs in [MySQL JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and I want to perform an action for each item in the list.

A naive solution is to do a WHILE loop with a counter that starts at 0 and ends when VAR_MANAGER_ID is null. Here is a contrived example of how the inside of the WHILE loop would look:

```
SET VAR_PATH = CONCAT('$[', COUNTER, ']');
SET VAR_MANAGER_ID = JSON_PARSE(VAR_MANAGER_IDS, PATH);

# See if we've reached the end of the list
IF VAR_MANAGER_ID IS NULL
THEN 
    BREAK
END;
INSERT INTO LU_MANAGER (MANAGER_ID) VALUES (VAR_MANAGER_ID);
```

But there has to be a better way! How can I do something like:

```
FOREACH JSON_PARSE(VAR_MANAGER_IDS, '$[*]') AS VAR_MANAGER_ID
    INSERT INTO LU_MANAGER (MANAGER_ID) VALUES (VAR_MANAGER_ID);
```

Comment: You are looking for a feature as [common_schema :: foreach](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/foreach.html), however, in MySQL 5.7, [common_schema](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html) not seem to work properly.

Comment: Wow, common_schema looks great! However, that `foreach` doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for: it is called for every row of a collection, but `JSON_PARSE` returns a single row.

Comment: [foreach :: A constants set](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/foreach.html) can be useful, would something like: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.

Comment: Common Schema link is broken

Answer (score 13, accepted):

complete newbie here but I found a way to iterate a JSON array using `REPEAT`-`UNTIL`-`END REPEAT`

```
   REPEAT
        SET txt = JSON_EXTRACT(myjson, CONCAT("$[", indx, "]"));
        # use txt
        SET indx = indx + 1;
        UNTIL indx = JSON_LENGTH(myjson)
   END REPEAT;
```